# How to import org.red5.server.presentation.RTSPStream;

Tags: java, eclipse, axis, red5

In the other subject: [RED5 AXIS camera capturing & streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196102/red5-axis-camera-capturing-streaming) user tries to obtain video form AXIS cam. I also wanted use the RED5 libraries but when I try to use his code I cannot import:

```
import org.red5.server.presentation.RTSPStream;
```

I have added tens of jars which are provided here: http://www.red5.org/downloads/red5/1_0_1/

but still my eclipse window look like that:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to download AxisTest2.zip from the following link:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/red5interest/CnqjUowR_LE/V2N-ApyyNswJ